# compare a postcode string to a column of 3-4 character values

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to get a user to enter a postcode and then compare the first few characters to see if they exists in a column in a database.

Basically the postcode entered for example could be bt1 5ws. In the column in the sql server database there are beginning of postcodes for example bt1, bt10, iv1.

The idea is to find out what area the user is from.

```
var Pcode = storeDB.DeliveryPCodes.SingleOrDefault(x => x.PCode == Customer.PCode)).ToString();
```

the above code compares the whole postcode entered to the with the code in column and does not work.

i am using c#, mvc3, entity framework (code first) with sql server 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string methods like `StartsWith`

```
var code = Customer.PCode.SubString(0, 3);

var Pcode = storeDB.DeliveryPCodes.
   SingleOrDefault(x => x.PCode.StartsWith(code)).ToString();
```

Comment: how do i make sure the user enters minimum 6 characters? because at the moment they can just enter 1 as their postcode

Comment: @Beginner Decorate your `PCode` property with [StringLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute.aspx) attribute. You can give the minimum and maximum length for the property. MVC will automatically add the validations for it.

Comment: Also from the database it returns loads of values, as loads of the postcodes will begin with bt1 for example, you have bt1, bt11, bt12

Comment: @Beginner Then replace `var code = Customer.PCode.SubString(0, 3);` with `var code = Customer.PCode;` like @Ladislav shown

Comment: i used == to after i took away the last 3 characters

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string postCode = Customer.PCode;
var PCode = storeDB.DeliveryPCodes.FirstOrDefault(x => postcode.StartsWith(x.PCode))
```

Comment: from the database it returns loads of values, as loads of the postcodes will begin with bt1 for example, you have bt1, bt11, bt12

Comment: But that is valid result in your scenario.

Comment: i used == to after i took away the last 3 characters